# Java: While (true) not getting proper print

Tags: java

I started studying Java on my own and I have been doing online exercises.

I am having trouble getting the correct print: it is printing -1 instead of the last inputted year whenever I want to quit my program by typing -1. How do I fix this so it will print the last inputted year instead of the -1 ? I have tried so many things, for example arrayLists and other loops but I don't seem to get it working.

Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Miniprojekti4_3 {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int command = 0;
        int year = 0;
        int days = 365;

        try {
            System.out.println("The program will ask you to input years. You can quit by typing -1 ");        

            while (true) {
                System.out.print("Insert year: ");
                year = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());   
                if (year == -1) {
                        break;
                } 
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Error: program closing..");
             System.exit(1);
        }

        if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 400 == 0) {
              System.out.println("In the year " + year + " there is " + (days+1) +" days. "); 
        } else {
            // if the year is not a leap year
            System.out.println("In the year " + year + " there is " + days +" days. ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you move the entire if/else section that checks for leap years and displays days inside the while(true) block, you should get what you're looking for:

```
            while (true)
            {     
                System.out.print("Insert year: ");
                year = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());   
                if (year == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 400 == 0) // if the year is a leap year.
                {

                    System.out.println("In the year " + year + " there is " + (days+1) +" days. "); 
                }
                else // if the year is not a leap year
                {

                    System.out.println("In the year " + year + " there is " + days +" days. ");
                }   
            }
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for. Yes, the year is now correct but the loop is not working as intended. It should be looping ''insert year'' until the user inputs -1 and only after that print the ''In the year...'', not between the loops.

Comment: Then use continue statement instead of break statement.

Comment: Still, this won't get the result I am after. What I am looking for is the program to print ''in the year...'' ONLY once and after the user has inputted -1 aka exiting the loop, not between the ''input year'' looping. Now it prints -1 instead of the last inputted year. ("In the year -1 there is..'') instead of ("In the year 1992 there is...")

Answer (score 1):

You just need to keep track of the last valid year that was input by the user.  Here I just assign user input to a temp variable and then if it's not -1 it gets assigned to the year variable.  This way if the user enters a -1 it breaks from the loop and year still has the old value in it.  I also changed the scanner to use nextInt() instead of nextLine() because there were some weird issues going on with that.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Miniprojekti4_3 {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int year = 0;
        int days = 365;

        try {
            System.out.println("The program will ask you to input years. You can quit by typing -1 ");

            while (true) {
                System.out.print("Insert year: ");
                int tempYear = input.nextInt();
                if (tempYear == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                year = tempYear;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: program closing..");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)) {
            System.out.println("In the year " + year + " there is " + (days + 1) + " days. ");
        } else {
            // if the year is not a leap year
            System.out.println("In the year " + year + " there is " + days + " days. ");
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Added in leap year logic from the post by ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa.

Comment: ! thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for. Gosh it seemed so simple fix now that I look at it and understood what I did wrong :) EDIT: are you sure about the leap year? Eclipse is giving error (Syntax error on token "||", invalid OnlySynchronized) when using your code ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0), but works when I add one more ) to the end  || (year % 400 == 0))

Comment: I edited in the leap year logic.  It should work as is now.  There was originally a parenthesis in the wrong location.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put this code inside the while loop:

```
 if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 400 == 0) {
          System.out.println("In the year " + year + " there is " + (days+1) +" days. "); 
    } else {
        // if the year is not a leap year
        System.out.println("In the year " + year + " there is " + days +" days. ");
    }
```

Then after the close of the catch statement, I'd put something like:

```
System.out.println("Exiting....");
```

Comment: I tried this but it's not printing the result I want to. The point is not to loop the ''In the year ...'' between asking the ''insert year'' from the user, but to print it once the user has inputted -1 to exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The output print is correct . But your looping is wrong.. Actually when you give -1 it is not actually terminates the program rather it breaks the loop and comes out of while loop alone. The if ... else statement below the catch block is executed and the year is getting printed, in your case it's -1. So inside the if statement where you check year == -1 type System.exit(1) instead of break statement.

Comment: Wont this stop the program and not print the ''in the year...'' part at all ?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you are setting year to -1 when you want the last user input that is not -1, so you should set command to user input check if it is -1. If it is -1 break. If it is not -1 set year to command.

Answer (score -1):

Your condition for  a leap year should be:

```
((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0)
```

[image]

from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) and [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/leap-years.html)

Comment: True, but this does not answer the actual question.